# Create a list with values not contained in a Google Sheets column via Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

My attempt was to work with `filter + includes`:

```
function not_contains() {
  var new_opt = [['a'],['b'],['d']];

  var col_g = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('test_stack').getRange('G1:G').getValues();
  // [['a'],['b'],['c'],[''],['']]

  var not_match = new_opt.filter(x => !col_g.includes(x));
}
```

Actual Result:

```
[ [ 'a' ], [ 'b' ], [ 'd' ] ]
```

Expected Result:

```
[ [ 'd' ] ]
```

Comment: Use `.flat()` on both arrays before filtering.

Comment: Hi @TheMaster the problem is that the lists within the list will be lost because it generates a single list, correct? This will get in the way when sending to the spreadsheet. Now I realized that my approach is wrong to work lists in list, how would you tell me to do so I don't lose the separate indexes?

Comment: Array structure will be preserved on `new_opt` in the method below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a 2D array, and `includes` only compares  primitives#strings directly, but not  array objects, use [Array.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) on one array:

```
const col_g_flat = col_g.flat();//// ['a','b','c',..]
const not_match = new_opt.filter(x => !col_g_flat.includes(x/*access the string inside*/[0]));
```